# Bootstrap: Remove form field border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to CSS and I am using Bootstrap and I want to use forms in 2 ways: With or without borders around the form fields. How can I achieve that best? Here is an example of a Bootstrap form I want to remove the borders for: plnkr.co/edit/xxx1Wy4kyCESNsChK4Ra?p=preview.

For curiosity, the reason I want this, is that I want to first show the user the data he has, and then toggle showing the borders according to if the form is in "edit" mode or not. The user can enter "edit" mode by clicking an "edit"-link or just start editing a field.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In that example, to remove the border simply write:

```
.form-control {
    border: 0;
}
```

In your CSS file.

This will remove borders from all your form fields though, a more flexible approach would be to attach a class to the form fields you want to have no border, so your HTML would be something like:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control no-border" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
```

and your CSS:

```
.no-border {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none; /* You may want to include this as bootstrap applies these styles too */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Jon! One thing, there is a shadow-thing still present after the no-border-class is applied (and I did not forget to copy the box-shadow-line). See the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xxx1Wy4kyCESNsChK4Ra?p=preview

Comment: Sorry @EricC i've updated my answer, it should be `box-shadow: none;` instead of `box-shadow: 0;` - that will remove the shadow.

Comment: A quick related question, Jon, maybe you know that one too: For a drop down list, there is a small arrow-up and arrow-down symbol on the right hand side. Is there a way to remove that also visually with CSS?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to give an exact answer, but bootstrap usually puts down arrows in like this `<span class="caret"></span>` you could target that class in your CSS and tell it to `display: none;` ... for example `.caret { display: none; }`. Once again this will hide anything with a class of `.caret`. A better method would be to either add `.hide` to the HTML (`<span class="caret hide"></span>`) or just delete that line of HTML. Hope this helps @EricC

Answer (score 29):

In Bootstrap 4, you can add `border-0` class to your element to remove its border.

Other classes that you can use - [Bootstrap 4 Borders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/)

```
<span class="border-0"></span>             /* remove all borders */
<span class="border-top-0"></span>         /* remove top border */
<span class="border-right-0"></span>       /* remove border on the right */
<span class="border-bottom-0"></span>      /* remove bottom border */
<span class="border-left-0"></span>        /* remove border on the left */
```

And here is a working example for what you asked:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#myInput").toggleClass('border-0')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="myInput">
  <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Toggle Border">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Border class from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/#border) v5.2.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" class="border-0" value="" placeholder="Enter value" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can remove the `border` class in your example. The `border` class sets a border which is then removed by `border-0`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the bootstrap default border/Shadow from input you can use the bootstrap built-in class **shadow-none**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none" placeholder="Enter name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went straight to the "inputs".

```css
input {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
```

This will remove all the borders of your form-inputs.