# Remove border from input box bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am creating a website using bootstrap, less and angular and I've been struggling all day with the input field for search bar. I tried using the bootstrap input-group with both input-group-addon and input-group-button but I cannot seem to be able to remove the border between the button and the input. Actually I cannot change the border at all. Any suggestions on how I could do this. I would like my search box have the same behaviour as in [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/).

UPDATE:

```
<form role="form" action="results.html" style="padding:30px">
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" /> <span class="input-group-addon" style="border-left-width: 0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="web" />
</p>
```

So this is my code. I don't know how to make a JSFiddle with it so that the bootstrap styling is preserved. I have also tried putting the html and css from this link http://jsfiddle.net/CbGpP/2/ into my code and the line between the button and input is still preserved, neither it turns green on click.

Comment: Share your code via http://jsfiddle.net/, so we can see your code online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being very silly, in the index.html I have added bootstrap stylesheet then my custom one and again bootstrap. Deleting last line solved all my problems.

Answer (score 8):

If I got you right then making `outline: 0` should solve your problem.

If I got it wrong, please post some pictures so that we can see your actual problem and also post the codes of what you've tried till now.

**EDIT:**

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f257xosu/):

Basically, you need to remove the right border of the text field, left border of the icon and background color of the icon.

Added a class `search-input` to the text field and `search-icon` to the icon.

Here is the CSS:

```
.search-input {
    border-right: 0;
}

.search-icon {
    border-left:0 solid transparent;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: changing to outline: 0 on the element within the browser (Chrome) did not change anything.

Comment: [Image](http://www.resizemyimage.net/images/71ad5968-b3fa-4439-a693-feea137790ac/Screenshot%20from%202015-02-04%2020:07:08.png) here is how the jsfiddle and my code looks on my page

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it now. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 8):

In Bootstrap 4 you can easily use it as below.

```
<span class="border-0"></span>
```

In Your case

```
<form role="form" action="results.html" style="padding:30px">
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" name="q" /> <span class="input-group-addon" style="border-left-width: 0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="web" />
</p>
```

Official Documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

Answer (score 1):

Setting `border:none;` should do it.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I put border:none; or outline:0; they all seem to be overriden. Also I don't understand why putting the code from JsFiddle wouldn't work, again the attributes seem to be overridden by something.

Comment: Here's an updated, working, version of your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CbGpP/58/).. It's not 100% there but its along the right path

Comment: Sorry, won't let me edit my previous comment, here's the right link: (http://jsfiddle.net/CbGpP/61/)

Answer (score 0):

This question answered in this link [Bootstrap: Remove form field border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033426/bootstrap-remove-form-field-border)

Basically what you have to do just add the following css to the form-control class

```
.form-control {
    border: 0;
  }
```

After this, you will get the input box without border.

OR Also you can do like that

```
.no-border {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none; /* You may want to include this as bootstrap applies these styles too */
     }
```

Comment: +1 on box shadow. I've overlooked this for a moment. After a deep zoom the gradient of the shadow was visible. Without the zoom the shadow seemed like a normal gray border.